Why do people accept long online games and then complain that I spend a lot of time?
I understand why people could prefer to play blitz games rather than long games. What I don't understand is why people accept my long time control challenges (such as 60 or 90 minutes per player) and then they blitz out all their moves and then they complain that I spend a lot of time and they demand that I play fast and then (when I refuse to speed up the pace) they disconnect. This doesn't happen only occasionally. This happens like half of the time. This happens on all chess playing websites.
I thought that maybe they accidentally click on my challenges. But then why don't they just abort the game immediately? Do they only realize that it's a long time control game after they've already made a few moves?
When my opponent spends a lot of time pondering about his moves, this does not bother me at all, I just watch some Youtube videos or do some reading while he ponders about his moves. The only problem is that sometimes I don't hear the sound.

Mute chat. Nothing good ever came out of an online chess chat

Unless you are playing a friend

What rating range are you. I am 2100+ Classical on Lichess and this never happens. Now aside from that, do you spend too much time in “not so complicated” positions? Do you spend too much time in opening?
The truth is, there is a perceived tempo and pace to the game. People are expected to play a move in “reasonable” amount of time in a position where there are a number of equally good moves.
People play long games to end up in interesting and complex positions where they then use their extra time to ponder deeper and learn something from such process, and practice calculations. They do not wish to wait 10 minutes for their opponent to play the 5th theory move of an opening. Even if they end up winning the game easily after their opponent runs into sever time trouble by move 15, they won’t learn anything from that game and it will not be worth their time. Unlike blitz or bullet a win is not a win in classical!
Maybe you should reveiew you time management more objectively and critically and hopefully you learn something from it. In fact, I suffered from the same and after investigating I found the root of the problem: I insisted on playing the best (only best) move in every position. This is wrong approach and even GM’s do not go with that. Being practical is the key. This helped me a lot. Not just time managemnet wise but my whole attitude to finding candidate moves and making up my mind. Hope you can do a similar thing.

""People are expected to play a move in “reasonable” amount of time in a position where there are a number of equally good moves."" In OTB chess with time controls, I've never experienced such an expectation. I often play a lot slower than my opponents, sometimes it's clear that they are bored, but nobody ever suggested I should be playing faster for their sake.

OTB etiquette is different. It is rude if not illegal to talk to your opponent OTB except for “adjust”, “sorry” (I hot your leg accidentally), and “draw?”  They may have been repearing that sentence in their minds though.

Oh and also most people will be happy with a win regardless of how it happens.
